# Count of one of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the dataset that looks like:

```
col1  col2  col3
a     2     20
a     3     12
a     4     34
b     2     44
c     3     23
c     5     13
```

....

What I want is a count of col1.

Output:

```
col1  col2  col3  count
a     2     20    3
a     3     12    3
a     4     34    3
b     2     44    1
c     3     23    2
c     5     13    2
```

.......

I know I can do by:

```
with cte as (
select col1, count(*) count
from tab1)
select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,cte.count
from tab1
join cte on a.col1=cte.col1
```

But is there any other I can do that without cross apply or cte?

Also, assuming there are more than 3 letters in col1, so I couldn't use sum function either:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ItemID = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_a
```

Comment: Try using `COUNT OVER`: `SELECT *,
 COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY col1)
FROM tab1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008+, you can use `COUNT() OVER()`:

```
SELECT *,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY col1)
FROM tab1
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/487343)</kbd>